# Can I extract an audio clip (a single word) from the video and insert at different points/timeline of same video using FFMPEG/libvlcsharp?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, fluent-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg, libvlcsharp

I want to load a video that has a soundtrack, and I want it to take an audio clip of a single spoken word and I want the clip inserted at different points in the video. The output will be the new video. I also want to insert an image at certain points in the video (watermark).

Can I do this using FFMPEG or libvlcsharp?

Comment: Probably not with libvlc(sharp), which is about playing videos, not making advanced manipulations like that. FFMPEG would probably give more flexibility about that, but I never used it.

Comment: I see, I got success for extracting a word from the clip but still searching for the solution to add at different points